# What does "__svnversion__" mean in Python Source Code

Tags: python, version-control

Recently, I saw the following piece of code in a python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
__svnversion__ = '$Id: setup.py 303 2010-10-20 02:51:64Z xyz $'    
import sys
```

It seems that it is a way to somehow keep track of version of the script in the SVN but I exactly don't know why and how it is used?. Where can I read more in general about this style of coding and why people use it?

Comment: I don't think it's common. Where did you see it?

Comment: Download the tar.gz from here [link](http://stuffivelearned.org/lib/exe/fetch.php?media=programming:python:clwatch-0.3.5.tar.gz) and see the file setup.py

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It doesn't mean anything; the author of that program just decided to create a variable with that name.

The `'$Id: setup.py 303 2010-10-20 02:51:64Z xyz $'` bit allows svn to automatically update the version number; presumably somewhere else in the code this value is displayed or sent with debugging output or something.

[PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#version-bookkeeping) suggests putting this in `__version__`, but rather disparagingly ("If you have to have [...] crud").

Comment: And the author probably shouldn't have created a variable with that name since `__name__` variables are "reserved" (liable to be given special meaning at any time) by python, although this one's probably pretty safe ...

Comment: @Wooble: Not sure what you mean by "allows svn to automatically update the version number". Are you referring to the SVN commit number? Also, suppose when the author changes the source code, does they manually update the "__version__" string? How are they able to accurately specify the time in seconds (HH:MM::64)? Or do they simply just put any value in the seconds as a best guess?

Comment: subversion itself rewrites the stuff between the `$` on commit; it doesn't have to be manually updated.

Comment: Yeah, I just too figured out the whole keyword expansion [deal](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.props.special.keywords.html) after posting my comment. Thanks for confirming though.

Answer (score 0):

Also, the following [PEP 396](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0396/) gives a good background and history including User Stories regarding the use of "_ *version*_" attribute in the python source code.